# Unable to build open cv 2.3.1 source code

Tags: opencv

I installed open cv in my ubuntu 11.04. But whenever I try to run any code I get the following error:

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /home/robik/Downloads/Java/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 275
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/robik/Downloads/Java/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:275: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow

I already have libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config in my OS. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

re configure and then re-run cmake. checkout this [tutorial](http://www.samontab.com/web/2011/06/installing-opencv-2-2-in-ubuntu-11-04/)

Comment: I'm getting the same error while doing it in Eclipse using NDK. 

Any idea how to debug that.? 

Thanks in advance :)