# opencvlibrary 2.4 installation

Tags: opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to build open cv 2.3.1 source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035537/unable-to-build-open-cv-2-3-1-source-code)

when i tested the sample program called "facedetect", this is the error which i got .Please let me know where i went wrong (in installation procedure or anything else )

OS:Fedora 17

ERROR:
./facedetect lena.jpg

This program demonstrates the cascade recognizer. Now you can use Haar or LBP features.
This classifier can recognize many ~rigid objects, it's most known use is for faces.
Usage:
./facedetect [--cascade= this is the primary trained classifier such as frontal face]
   [--nested-cascade[=nested_cascade_path this an optional secondary classifier such as eyes]]
   [--scale=
   [filename|camera_index]

see facedetect.cmd for one call:
./facedetect --cascade="../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" --nested-cascade="../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml" --scale=1.3 
Hit any key to quit.
Using OpenCV version 2.4.0

Processing 1 lena.jpg
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /home/srinath/Documents/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 598
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/srinath/Documents/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:598: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow

Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: are you sure that the  "./facedetect lena.jpg" is exist ??

Comment: im new to opencv , can you tell me where the error lies??

Comment: @SantoshSrinath error never lies, it always says true :)